# rvm does not set ruby version

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

i am new to linux. i have kubuntu 11.10 , i have installed ruby 1.9.2 and only after this i have installed rvm. after this i made

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

and

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

and when i use

```
rvm use 1.8.7
ruby -v
```

it writes

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

i tryed to use another versions but it writes same anyway, so i think that rvm dont have priority to choose ruby version. how to solve this problem? It's cause i have installed ruby and only after this i have installed rvm?

Comment: how did you install RVM?   under your user-account or as root?

Comment: can you post the output of `printenv | grep rvm`

Comment: i think that i installed it like user-account

Comment: a couple of questions: - how did you install RVM? under your user-account or as root? - can you post the output of `printenv | grep rvm` - what is the output of `rvm list`

Comment: grep rvm dont have output(i am new to linux so i can do something wrong)

Comment: here is printend output http://www.pastie.org/2791214

Comment: @cHao deleting an answer in-progress is really not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the output of your `rvm list`, you have two rubies installed, none of them default.

**Looks like you just missed the step to make 1.9.2 the default**.

And it seems **you didn't modify your `.bash_profile` file**

**See Step 3 on this page:**

http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Your file `~/.bash_profile` should contain this line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

(make sure to start a new shell, after modifying .bash_profile)

**Then run this:** (to set the default Ruby version)

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2

ruby -v
```

See also:

http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/

Answer (score 0):

First you should establish if rvm is installed correctly, you can determine that by entering `type rvm | head -1` in your terminal.  If you get the response `rvm is a function` then rvm is installed correctly.

If it's an installation problem carefully go back over each step, if you still can't figure out what's wrong I highly recommend visiting the #rvm channel on freenode (irc).  The creator and other knowledgeable rvmers are almost always available, friendly and willing to help you troubleshoot.  If you end up using ruby extensively, you're going to start needing more of the functionality rvm offers (gemsets, etc.) and #rvm can be a great resource when you get tripped up.